# UIWebView Replace DIV with another

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, uiwebview

I am building a WebView iOS app and want to replace one div with another div.

The current HTML code loaded

```
<div class="cart-text">
  <!-- add to cart -->
  <a class="" onclick="cart.add('563', ''); fbq('track', 'AddToCart');" title="Add to Bag">+<span> Add to Bag</span></a>
</div>
```

Needs to be replaced with:

```
<button type="submit" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Add to Bag <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

How is it possible to do this? Thank you!

Comment: You should at least try something and post your initial test, that shows us that you're not just asking for the community to code this for you.